# Как записать целую команду в 1 букву?

Tags: java, c++, шаблоны-с++

Мне надоедает и иногда лень писать команду `(cout << "текст";)`,
поэтому хочу поместить всю строку `cout << "текст";` в букву `c`.

Приведу пример на Java, я не помню как называется такая вещь и впрочем-то как пишется:

- Полная команда - `player` .
- Нам нужно ещё сократить по максимальному - `p`.

И вместо того, чтобы писать `player.getinfo;`, будем писать `p.getinfo;`.

Comment: `#define с cout << "текст";` - это вы хотите?...

Comment: В какую команду? Речь о какой-то IDE или о чём вообще?

Comment: @Harry кажется это он и имел ввиду..

Comment: @Harry да, а как продолжить, саму команду cout назвал "pod"

Comment: @Harry 
#define pod cout << "jarry" ;
 pod(); (в скобки хочу вписать то - что будет выводиться в консоль, например jarry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все, что вам нужно -

```
#define  pod(x)  cout << x;
```

или

```
template<typename T>
void pod(T x)  { cout << x; }
```

И вперед -

```
int main()
{
    pod("text")
    pod(8)
}
```

Но большого (откровенно - никакого) смысла в этом я не вижу...

Comment: Удаляю свой ответ - Ваш лучше :)